# Time slot coming from server

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm working on iOS app where I have time slots like this `["10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:30 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:30 PM", "1:00 PM", "1:30 PM", "2:00 PM", "2:30 PM", "3:00 PM"]` PM it should show from 12pm and if I select next day it will show whole array from starting to end.

I'm using this code:

```
func timeSlots(startTime: String, endTime: String, leadTime: Int, timeInterval: Int) {        
    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    timeFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

    let startingTime = timeFormatter.date(from: startTime)
    let endingTime = timeFormatter.date(from: endTime)

    for i in 0 ... 20 {
        guard let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute , value: i*timeInterval, to: firstTimeSlot!) else { return }

        timeArray.append(timeFormatter.string(from: newDate).localizedUppercase)
        // timeArray[0] = "Immediate"
    }

    print(timeArray)
}
```

Comment: What is firstTimeSlot?

Comment: What exactly is the question? What is the input, actual output and expected output?

Comment: Martin R :- i am getting this kind of tym array ["10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:30 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:30 PM", "1:00 PM", "1:30 PM", "2:00 PM", "2:30 PM", "3:00 PM"],